# GHC could not execute htfpp

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am getting this error

```
ghc: could not execute: htfpp
```

when I try to load a file with `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF htfpp #-}` in its header.
I have installed htf successfully (v0.12)

How can I solve this (on Linux and on Windows)

Thank you!

Comment: Where is `htfpp` located? Is it in your `$PATH`?

Comment: No, it is not, how can I find out where it is located? Indeed, that could be the problem.

Comment: Look in `~/.cabal` for a `config` file and scan those definitions for possible locations. Perhaps its `extra-prog-path` or a `bindir` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

community-wiki answer for posterity:

`htfpp` was not in the path. To find how to alter the path, one looks in the `~/.cabal` folder for a `config` file and finds where cabal installs binaries by default. That directory needs to be added to the path, or the installed binary needs to be moved from there to a directory that *is* in the path. Then GHC can run it with the `-pgmF` flag.